# Issue with long running queries after upgrading MariaDB 10.2 to 10.6 (queries can't be killed)

Tags: database, mariadb, amazon-rds

We have upgraded our RDS Database from MariaDB 10.2 to 10.6 (LTS version), since then we started noticing some issues with the queries being blocked, these queries would lock the table and it would cause more blocked queries.

The queries would never stop running even after I changing some default variables like `connect_timeout`.

[image]

After reaching 7200s the queries would be killed by the database itself (state change to KILLED) but they would still appear with

```
show full processlist;
```

Even Killing the queries manually do not work either, only the state would change to KILLED but the connection would still be open:

[image]

As a result the number of connections increases and the only option we have is to restart the database, sometime the database itself would stop responding after it reaches 800 open connections...

Restarting the database would take 15 min and we can't keep restarting it to kill the open connections!

Here is the output for `show global status;`

The values we have before restarting the DB (we have a lot of blocked open connections)
https://pastebin.com/dz70FXBJ

The values we have after restarting and everything should be stable:
https://pastebin.com/C061EAY3

Comment: Statistics of tables are cached, so if you are getting a lot of queries continuously on the same table in that state I'd suggest raising the [table_open_cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#table_open_cache). Include `show global status` information a interval after changing the server variables and `flush status`.

Comment: I have increased the value to 6000 but it still didn't help, here is the the result I get when I run show global status: https://pastebin.com/dz70FXBJ 
Should I increase the value even more ? the default value was GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/21474836480)*5000},2000) but I have no idea how high could I go
Could the issue be something else as well because even Insert or update queries could be blocks not just Statistics (even so most of them is Statistics)

Comment: `Open_tables` < 2k so right, it didn't help, too much of a guess. `Innodb_history_list_length` of 57M is large. Do you have a long running transaction? though it could be the innodb flushing isn't keeping up (which could explain the 15m restart time). `Created_tmp_disk_tables` / `Created_tmp_tables` is large per `uptime`  or per `com_select`. Are you using a tmpfs or fast storage. innodb buffer pool efficiency is good. Next suggestion is increase `innodb_log_file_size` to a few G, but I'd wait for other people to offer their input too. I don't quite understand the common `Statistics` statusyet

Comment: Thanks you again for your reply, the issue got better but it still would happen.
When checking the metrics I saw that the number of blocked transaction would increase by time, killing the query it self as mentioned won't stop the transaction as the query would only change status to killed:
```
select * from information_schema.innodb_trx;
```
That query would show transaction that stay there forever, I did notice this new values that were added to mariaDB 10.3 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#idle_transaction_timeout I changed it to 3600 but not sure if it would fix it.

Comment: Changing innodb_log_file_size didn't help much
When this issue happen with "show open tables" I see that every time a table have a lot of opening, it's not always the same table but generally the queries are always on the same data (same client id...)
We do have cronjobs that would keep trying to read or write to the table if the task do not take place which is why the connections numbers increases by time, we use Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) as storage type

Answer (score 0):

I've recently completed the very same MariaDB version update (from 10.2 to 10.6) and hit severe performance issues.

After investigating, I've also noticed a lot of queries being stuck in the "statistics" state for a long time (or even indefinitely), consuming all of the available CPU power.

In our case, the issue was the `optimizer_search_depth` variable, which caused the query engine to take exponential amount of time to come up with a query plan, depending on the amount of joins that the query has. The default value for the variable hasn't changed between the versions (it's 62), but the query optimisation logic has probably changed, causing the slowdown.

Changing the variable value to 0 solved the issue.

Blog post describing the issue and the solution:
https://conetix.com.au/support/slow-mariadb-sql-queries-in-statistics-state/

The `optimizer_search_depth` variable described in the MariaDB docs:
https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/optimizer_search_depth/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was an annoying issue, after spending quite some time looking into it, it turned out it's a Mariab DB issue with 10.6.8 version: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27983
We had to upgrade our DB to 10.6.10 and this has solved the issue.